# Relatively Open Subset, Proof

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, proof-writing

The exercise is:

> Let $ A \equiv [0, 1). $ Prove that $ B \subset A $ is relatively open in A only if it is open in $ \mathbb{R} $ or it contains $0$.

Context: We're talking metric spaces with a distance $ d$.

---

I wanted to ask **if my proof is watertight**:

> Let $ A \equiv [0, 1) $ and $ B \subset A.$
>
> WTS if $B$ is relatively open in $A$ then $0 \in B$ or $B$ open in $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Assume $ B \subset A $ is relatively open in $A$.
>
> Then $ \forall x \in B , \ \exists \varepsilon>0$ such that $\{ y \in A | d(x,y)<\varepsilon \} \subset B.$
>
> Assume $0 \not\in B$, so $B \subset \text{int}(A) $ where $\text{int}(A) \equiv \{ z \in A |\exists \varepsilon > 0, B_{\varepsilon}(z) \subset A \}. $
>
> Since $\forall x \in B, \exists \varepsilon>0$ such that $\{ y \in A | d(x,y)< \varepsilon \} \subset B\subset \text{int}(A)$ and $\text{int}(A)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$, it is the case that $\forall x \in B, \ \exists \varepsilon > 0$ such that $\{ y \in \mathbb{R} | d(x,y) < \varepsilon  \} \subset B.$
>
> Therefore, $B$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$You wrote near the end "it is the case that $\forall x \in B$, $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $\{y \in \R |d(x,y) < \epsilon \} \subset \color{red}{\R}$." However, to show that $B$ is open in $\R$, wouldn't you want to show that it's a subset of $B$ (i.e. show that for all $x$ in $B$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(x):= \{y \in \R |d(x,y) < \epsilon \}$ is a subset of $B$)?

Comment: Definitely, yes hahaha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since B is relatively open, there is an open set U, of R with B = A $\cap$ U.
There are two cases:  0 in B and 0 not in B.

In the second case, B is a subset of (0,1).
Thus B = (0,1) $\cap$ U, is the intersection of two open subsets of R, hence an open set of R.